# Fluid, access locallang.xlf from another extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I have a own template and in this template I overwrite the templates of the tx_news:

```
plugin.tx_news.view {

    templateRootPaths.1 = EXT:my_template/Resources/Private/News/Templates/
    partialRootPaths.1  = EXT:my_template/Resources/Private/News/Partials/
    layoutRootPaths.1 = EXT:my_template/Resources/Private/News/Layouts/
}
```

Now I would like to access the locallang.xlf from my_template. I tried this in the ext_table.php of my_template:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr(
    'tt_content.pi_flexform.news_pi1.list', 'EXT:my_template/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf');
```

And in this locallang.xlf I have:

```
    <trans-unit id="tx_mytemplate.news">
        <source>NEWSTEST</source>
    </trans-unit>
```

And then in the tx_news List.html I have:

```
<f:translate key="tx_mytemplate.news" />
```

But I do not get any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of accomplishing the task you are trying to do.

1. add the argument extensionName to the `f:translate` ViewHelper like so: `<f:translate key="tx_mytemplate.news" extensionName="MyTemplate" />`
2. add your locallang key as a full path like so `<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:my_template/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_mytemplate.news" />`

I would prefer the first way, because it is shorter and you can let extbase/fluid decide where to search for the file.